# Does a Future instantly return false for isDone() right after an executor submit()

Tags: java, future, executor

Could not find a documentation about the future state of an `executor.submit()` call.

Example:

```
byte[] b = new byte[ 4000000 ];
new Random().nextBytes( b );
Callable<byte[]> c = new SorterCallable( b );
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<byte[]> result = executor.submit( c );
boolean futureState = result.isDone();
```

The question is if the returned `Future<byte[]>` object returns false when calling `isDone()` right after submit?

Or is it also possible that `futureState` is `true` such that the submitted task has been executed before `boolean futureState = result.isDone();` ?

Comment: That depends entirely on how long the task takes and how threads are scheduled, I think.

Comment: Are you asking whether, in the short time period between the submission of the task and the examination of `isDone()`, whether the task *could* be executed? Or whether the very act of submitting the task causes `isDone()` to become `true`?

Comment: Doesn't it make sense that the executor constructs the Future with a default false value for isDone()?

Comment: @Readwald: I'm wondering if the very act of submitting constructs a Future with predefined false for isDone().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if the very act of submitting constructs a Future with predefined false for isDone()

Just check the source for the answer.

In the `FutureTask` constructor, the private 
field `state` is set to `NEW`. The `isDone()` method returns `state != NEW`. Hence, the moment the object is created, `isDone()` is theoretically false.

```
public FutureTask(Runnable runnable, V result) {
    this.callable = Executors.callable(runnable, result);
    this.state = NEW;       // ensure visibility of callable
}

public boolean isDone() {
    return state != NEW;
}
```

Of course, as described in [Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24385739/474189), your `futureState` variable may be true if the task has executed between the time you submitted it and the time you checked.

Comment: *"Hence, the moment the object is created, isDone() returns false."* - Ermm, I don't think this is right.  `isDone()` cannot be called until after the `FutureTask` has been created by its constructor.  It is not meaningful to say that `isDone()` returns anything until after a point in time when it *could* be called.  And between the end of construction and that point in time, it is theoretically possible for the scheduled task to run.  In fact, there is no point in the timeline of the current thread where you can guarantee that a real `isDone()` call won't return `true`.

Comment: @StephenC You are correct. I was referring, perhaps unclearly, to that impossible to achieve instance just after the constructor was called. I hope it's clear what I meant. Much like the convenient infinite piece of string or the surface with zero friction that is helpful in other fields of interest. I edited my wording to hopefully be clearer on that subject.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question

> Or is it also possible that futureState is true such that the submitted task has been executed before boolean futureState = result.isDone(); ?

Technically yes, it is possible. Thread scheduling might go in such a way that task is completed at once. But, in most cases you will get `false` IMO.