# Something weird with ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency

Sorry for the vague title, but I don't know how describe the problem succinctly.

Using a ScheduledExecutorService, I schedule a Runnable to run every 5 seconds without an initial delay. I have a shceduled task that calls shutdonw() on the ScheduledExecutorService after 60 seconds. When the shutdown occurs, it appears the main thread halts. It doesn't exit.

In the code below, "Ping" is correctly picked up from the blocking queue every 5 seconds. When the ScheduledExecutorService is shutdown, it stops printing "Ping", the line below the isDone() check doesn't get executed, nor does the logger at the end of the test, but Eclipse shows the test is still running.

**"Test" (doesn't test anything, just using it instead of a main() )**

```
package scheduledExecutorTest;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService;
import com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.MasterScheduler;

public class SchedulerTest {

private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerTest.class);
    @Test
    public void testScheduleTasks() throws InterruptedException {

        MasterScheduler.scheduleToRunOnceWithInitialDelay(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MasterScheduler.shutDown();
            }
        }, 60L);

        HeartBeatService heartbeatService = new HeartBeatService();
        heartbeatService.doStart();
        LOGGER.debug("doStart() returned");  //THIS NEVER GETS HIT
    }
}
```

**Heartbeat Service that schedules the heartbeat:**

```
package com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service;

import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.HeartBeat;

public class HeartBeatService {

    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartBeatService.class);

    public void doStart() throws InterruptedException {

        Scheduler<String> scheduler = new Scheduler<String>();
        ScheduledFuture<String> taskStatus = scheduler.scheduleToRunPeriodically(new HeartBeat(), 5L);

        try {
            while (taskStatus.isDone() == false) {
                LOGGER.debug(scheduler.getTaskOutput());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Something happened");
        }

        LOGGER.debug("COMPLETE"); //THIS NEVER GETS HIT

    }
}
```

**Scheduler:**

```
package com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.ScheduledTask;

public class Scheduler<T> {

    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Scheduler.class);
    private BlockingQueue<T> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(1);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ScheduledFuture<T> scheduleToRunPeriodically(ScheduledTask<T> scheduledTask,
            long timeIntervalSeconds) {

        Runnable task = transformIntoRunnable(scheduledTask);
        return (ScheduledFuture<T>) MasterScheduler.scheduleToRunPeriodically(task,
                timeIntervalSeconds);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ScheduledFuture<T> scheduleToRunPeriodicallyWithInitialDelay(
            ScheduledTask<T> scheduledTask, long repeatTimeIntervalSeconds,
            long initalDelaySeconds) {

        Runnable task = transformIntoRunnable(scheduledTask);
        return (ScheduledFuture<T>) MasterScheduler.scheduleToRunPeriodicallyWithInitialDelay(task,
                repeatTimeIntervalSeconds, initalDelaySeconds);
    }

    public void scheduleToRunOnceWithInitialDelay(ScheduledTask<T> scheduledTask,
            long timeIntervalSeconds) {

        Runnable task = transformIntoRunnable(scheduledTask);
        MasterScheduler.scheduleToRunOnceWithInitialDelay(task, timeIntervalSeconds);
    }

    private Runnable transformIntoRunnable(final ScheduledTask<T> scheduledTask) {
        LOGGER.debug("Converting ScheduledTask into Runnable");
        return () -> queue.add(scheduledTask.invoke());
    }

    public T getTaskOutput() throws InterruptedException {
        return queue.take();
    }

}
```

**Singleton Master Scheduler**

```
package com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MasterScheduler {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterScheduler.class);

    public static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 10;

    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);

    public static ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleToRunPeriodically(Runnable task, long timeIntervalSeconds) {

        LOGGER.debug("Scheduling task to run async every " + timeIntervalSeconds + " seconds without delay");
        return scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, timeIntervalSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleToRunPeriodicallyWithInitialDelay(Runnable task,
            long repeatTimeIntervalSeconds, long initalDelaySeconds) {

        LOGGER.debug("Seceduling task to run every " + repeatTimeIntervalSeconds + " seconds after initial delay of "
                + initalDelaySeconds + " seconds");

        return scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initalDelaySeconds, repeatTimeIntervalSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void scheduleToRunOnceWithInitialDelay(Runnable task, long timeIntervalSeconds) {

        scheduler.schedule(task, timeIntervalSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void shutDown() {
        System.err.println("SCHEDULER SHUTTING DOWN GRACEFULLY. NO NEW TASKS ALLOWED");
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Heatbeat (the task that is scheduled)**

```
package com.paul.scheduledexecutortest;

public class HeartBeat implements ScheduledTask<String> {

    @Override
    public String invoke() {
        return "Ping";
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
13:48:41.721 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.Scheduler - Converting ScheduledTask into Runnable
13:48:41.780 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.MasterScheduler - Scheduling task to run async every 5 without delay
13:48:41.781 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:48:46.807 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:48:51.782 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:48:56.782 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:01.782 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:06.783 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:11.783 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:16.783 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:21.784 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:26.783 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:31.783 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
13:49:36.783 [main] DEBUG com.paul.scheduledexecutortest.service.HeartBeatService - Ping
SCHEDULER SHUTTING DOWN GRACEFULLY. NO NEW TASKS ALLOWED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `doStart()` method is blocking, since `taskStatus.isDone()` is almost always false, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385611/does-a-future-instantly-return-false-for-isdone-right-after-an-executor-submit).

In your `Scheduler.java` class, why do you need a blocking queue when it only contains only 1 element?

I suggest to perform the below changes:

**Test.java:**

```
MasterScheduler.scheduleToRunOnceWithInitialDelay(() -> MasterScheduler.shutDown(), 60L);
HeartBeatService heartbeatService = new HeartBeatService();
heartbeatService.doStart();
```

**HeartBeatService:**

```
public void doStart() throws InterruptedException {
   Scheduler<String> scheduler = new Scheduler<String>();
   scheduler.scheduleToRunPeriodically(new HeartBeat(), 5L);
}
```

**Scheduler.java:**

```
private Runnable transformIntoRunnable(final ScheduledTask<T> scheduledTask) {
   LOGGER.debug("Converting ScheduledTask into Runnable");
   return () -> LOGGER.debug((String)scheduledTask.invoke());
}
```

**MasterScheduler.java:**

```
public static void shutDown() {
   System.err.println("SCHEDULER SHUTTING DOWN GRACEFULLY. NO NEW TASKS ALLOWED");
   scheduler.shutdown();
   try {
      if (!scheduler.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
         scheduler.shutdownNow();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
 }
```